# Create XML from SQL Server 2005 data using FOR XML

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, for-xml

I'm trying to create an Excel XML that I want to store in an XML Field in SQL Server 2005.  I have gotten this far:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
  'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' as "s",
  'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' as "o",
  'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' as "x"
)
select 'Order' as "@s:Name",
(
    select
        'String' as 's:Cell/s:Data/@s:Type',
        [Order] as 's:Cell/s:Data',
        null as 'tmp',
        'String' as 's:Cell/s:Data/@s:Type',
        [Material] as 's:Cell/s:Data',
        null as 'tmp',
        'String' as 's:Cell/s:Data/@s:Type',
        [Ship-To] as 's:Cell/s:Data'
    from
    (
        select
            'Order' as [Order],
            'Material' as [Material],
            'Ship-To' as [Ship-To]
        union all
        select
            [Order],
            [Material],
            [Ship-To]
        from Orders
        WHERE [Material] IN(1234,5678))
    ) as Temp
    FOR XML PATH('s:Row'), type
) AS 's:Table'
FOR XML PATH('s:Worksheet'), root('s:Workbook')
```

Here's my output:

```
<s:Workbook xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:s="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <s:Worksheet s:Name="Order">
    <s:Table>
      <s:Row xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:s="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Order</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Material</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Ship-To</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
      <s:Row xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:s="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">200909</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">1234</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">US</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
      <s:Row xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:s="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">200909</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">5678</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">ASIA</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
    </s:Table>
  </s:Worksheet>
</s:Workbook>
```

What I want is to eliminate the namespace in the `<s:Row>` node.  I want to get rid of this: `xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:s="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"` from `<s:Row xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:s="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">`

Anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Why do you want them eliminated? They are superflous, but correct.

Comment: I'm processing a great deal of data.  Though it works ok as it is right now, but it would be nice if I could trim what's really unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Each FOR XML clause will add a namespace declaration. The only way I know to get rid of them is to build the *entire* document in one single 'for xml' query, and that is not feasible.